# Load Inline Javascript after Scroll

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that is causing a really high Largest Contenful Paint:

I have tried defer but I was thinking maybe somehow loading this after user scrolls even one pixel should be enough but not before that to circumvent LCP entirely.

```js
<!-- Quantcast Choice. Consent Manager Tag v2.0 (for TCF 2.0) -->
<script type="text/javascript" async=true>
(function() {
  var host = window.location.hostname;
  var element = document.createElement('script');
  var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  var url = 'https://cmp.quantcast.com'
    .concat('/choice/', 'h05nHPpABpSs3', '/', host, '/choice.js');
  var uspTries = 0;
  var uspTriesLimit = 3;
  element.async = true;
  element.type = 'text/javascript';
  element.src = url;

  firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(element, firstScript);

  function makeStub() {
    var TCF_LOCATOR_NAME = '__tcfapiLocator';
    var queue = [];
    var win = window;
    var cmpFrame;

    function addFrame() {
      var doc = win.document;
      var otherCMP = !!(win.frames[TCF_LOCATOR_NAME]);

      if (!otherCMP) {
        if (doc.body) {
          var iframe = doc.createElement('iframe');

          iframe.style.cssText = 'display:none';
          iframe.name = TCF_LOCATOR_NAME;
          doc.body.appendChild(iframe);
        } else {
          setTimeout(addFrame, 5);
        }
      }
      return !otherCMP;
    }

    function tcfAPIHandler() {
      var gdprApplies;
      var args = arguments;

      if (!args.length) {
        return queue;
      } else if (args[0] === 'setGdprApplies') {
        if (
          args.length > 3 &&
          args[2] === 2 &&
          typeof args[3] === 'boolean'
        ) {
          gdprApplies = args[3];
          if (typeof args[2] === 'function') {
            args[2]('set', true);
          }
        }
      } else if (args[0] === 'ping') {
        var retr = {
          gdprApplies: gdprApplies,
          cmpLoaded: false,
          cmpStatus: 'stub'
        };

        if (typeof args[2] === 'function') {
          args[2](retr);
        }
      } else {
        if(args[0] === 'init' && typeof args[3] === 'object') {
          args[3] = { ...args[3], tag_version: 'V2' };
        }
        queue.push(args);
      }
    }

    function postMessageEventHandler(event) {
      var msgIsString = typeof event.data === 'string';
      var json = {};

      try {
        if (msgIsString) {
          json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        } else {
          json = event.data;
        }
      } catch (ignore) {}

      var payload = json.__tcfapiCall;

      if (payload) {
        window.__tcfapi(
          payload.command,
          payload.version,
          function(retValue, success) {
            var returnMsg = {
              __tcfapiReturn: {
                returnValue: retValue,
                success: success,
                callId: payload.callId
              }
            };
            if (msgIsString) {
              returnMsg = JSON.stringify(returnMsg);
            }
            if (event && event.source && event.source.postMessage) {
              event.source.postMessage(returnMsg, '*');
            }
          },
          payload.parameter
        );
      }
    }

    while (win) {
      try {
        if (win.frames[TCF_LOCATOR_NAME]) {
          cmpFrame = win;
          break;
        }
      } catch (ignore) {}

      if (win === window.top) {
        break;
      }
      win = win.parent;
    }
    if (!cmpFrame) {
      addFrame();
      win.__tcfapi = tcfAPIHandler;
      win.addEventListener('message', postMessageEventHandler, false);
    }
  };

  makeStub();

  var uspStubFunction = function() {
    var arg = arguments;
    if (typeof window.__uspapi !== uspStubFunction) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (typeof window.__uspapi !== 'undefined') {
          window.__uspapi.apply(window.__uspapi, arg);
        }
      }, 500);
    }
  };

  var checkIfUspIsReady = function() {
    uspTries++;
    if (window.__uspapi === uspStubFunction && uspTries < uspTriesLimit) {
      console.warn('USP is not accessible');
    } else {
      clearInterval(uspInterval);
    }
  };

  if (typeof window.__uspapi === 'undefined') {
    window.__uspapi = uspStubFunction;
    var uspInterval = setInterval(checkIfUspIsReady, 6000);
  }
})();
</script>
<!-- End Quantcast Choice. Consent Manager Tag v2.0 (for TCF 2.0) -->
```

I have tried async=defer.
I have also tried the following:

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        (function($) {
            //whole script here
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looking for a scroll event?

```
let isScriptLoaded = false;

function onScroll() {
  if (!isScriptLoaded) {
    // whole script here

   isScriptLoaded = true;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```